# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor View Restrictions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I apologize in advance for the generic nature of my question, but I was unable to find any helpful advice from people trying to do the same thing as me on the web. Let me describe my scenario:

I am providing end users/designers of a website the ability to customize their views by storing the views (using Razor) in the database. I have all of this working, but my question is the following; From a security standpoint, how can I ensure and enforce that unwanted code doesn't get executed in the user-defined view? There are two basic approaches that I think will work conceptually, but am not sure which one is more possible or feasible.

Option 1: Create a validation method in the administration tool that allows the user to input the view code. This would need to either take a whitelist or blacklist approach to what is allowable or not.

Option 2: Prevent unwanted code from being able to execute when rendering of the view occurs.

As a quick example of something that would need to be blocked, we wouldn't want to allow access to read or write files, access any data access functions, or even access configuration settings, etc. in the web.config. There will likely be a decently-sized list of things that probably shouldn't be allowable, but I'll need to sit down and try to think of as many security-related concerns as possible.

My question then is, which method would be the best bet? Also, can any direction be provided on how to go about either? I thought I might be able to make trust-level based change which would be Option 2, but couldn't find any way to make that work in a per-view based manor (the administration code is allowed to execute whatever it wants). I'm thinking Option 1 will end up being the best bet and I'll have to check for the input of certain framework functions that shouldn't be allowed. Does anyone have any experience doing anything like what I'm trying to do? ANY feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Option 2 would be terrible from a user's perspective who may try to use code that he or she otherwise didn't know was 'bad'. I agree with SLaks a white list approach would be better, and I don't know the exact nature of your project such as who are your consumers but this will a difficult task depending on how much flexibility you need to give them.

Comment: I was going to suggest you check out Liquid markup, then I found [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/try-online). It looks like it covers what you're trying to accomplish (but with Liquid instead of Razor).

Answer (score 1):

This would be extremely difficult.

You could run the the template through the Razor preprocessor, then use Roslyn (still in early beta) to parse the generated file and look through all method calls (or constructors) and return an error if it calls something you don't like.
I strongly recommend that you use a whitelist for that, since the .Net framework is big enough that you are bound to overlook something in a blacklist.

---

However, I would instead recommend that you not use Razor at all and instead use a templating engine that does not allow real C# code.

Comment: I originally DID start out with a custom templating engine, but there seems to be many advantages to sticking with the Razor view engine. i.e. built-in ability for common view programming tasks like conditionals, loops, and the fact that it provides access to the model. Plus it seems like the built-in caching mechanism will save a lot of resources instead of me having to implement something more custom for a custom templating system. The only real drawback I can find (although it is obviously a serious drawback) is security. If you can think of more drawbacks, that might make me reconsider.